# uiwebview request set httpBody

Tags: ios, uiwebview, request, uiwebviewdelegate

I am working in a UIWebView ios app.

in the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

I get the body as follow:

```
NSString *stringPost = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

It works ok, but now, i would like to add a parameter to the body and I try it as follow:

```
NSMutableData *myBody = [NSMutableData dataWithData:request.HTTPBody];

[myBody appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"isNative", @"TRUE"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:myBody];
```

it not works.

Any idea of how to add parameters to my httpBody?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify format for string then you are in need of indicate which format would be used (like `%@`, `%d`, `%.2f` e.g.). I'm not sure what you want to specify, but you need to use `stringWithFormat` somethig like this

```
[myBody appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"isNative = %@", @"TRUE"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```